# SMS Keywords: Geo

Tags: iphone, android, sms

I've created an application that will send you the Lat/Long of a location and was wondering if there was a uniform way of sending it via Text Message such that Android or iPhone might allow the user to click it and open that location in a map.

Yes, Android has geocoder which will tell you the address but sometimes that takes too long or is unable to find anything useful.

I've looked through and android has the geo keyword for intent, but I don't think a SMS will respond to that, does anyone know of a uniform way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no such common keyword is implemented. Android will handle **geo** URIs, but to the best of my knowledge those are not natively handled by any other platforms (and on Android its only Google-branded devices with Google Maps installed that will *natively* handle them).

You might want to build a trivial handler for the other platforms: it might require installable software, but shouldn't be TOO painful.

Comment: and the geo URI, if I put that in a message, say geo:24,-42 it *should* show up as something clickable by the default message app for the phone?